# fs.readFileSync adding + signs?

Tags: node.js, fs

I am working on an HTTP fileserver and stumbled upon a problem with fs.readFileSync(). However, the function adds + signs which prohibits me from writing the value to another value.

(This is just to show what happens and does not represent the full functionality of the intended code)

> samplejs.js

```
var content = fs.readFileSync("D:/sampleproj/example.txt", {encoding:"utf8"});
console.log(content);
```

output:

```
  "\t'#0000CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0000FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0033CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0033FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0066CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0066FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0099CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#0099FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#00CC00',\r" +
  "\n\t'#00CC33',\r" +
  "\n\t'#00CC66',\r" +
  "\n\t'#00CC99',\r" +
  "\n\t'#00CCCC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#00CCFF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3300CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3300FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3333CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3333FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3366CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3366FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3399CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#3399FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#33CC00',\r" +
  "\n\t'#33CC33',\r" +
  "\n\t'#33CC66',\r" +
  "\n\t'#33CC99',\r" +
  "\n\t'#33CCCC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#33CCFF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#6600CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#6600FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#6633CC',\r" +
  "\n\t'#6633FF',\r" +
  "\n\t'#66CC00',\r" +
```

The problem here is, of course, the + signs. How can these be "avoided"/removed?
I've tried to .split("+") but that doesn't work since the + signs aren't inside a pair of quotes.

the text file:

    `'#0000CC',
    '#0000FF',
    '#0033CC',
    '#0033FF',
    '#0066CC',
    '#0066FF',
    '#0099CC',
    '#0099FF',
    '#00CC00',
    '#00CC33',
    '#00CC66',
    '#00CC99',
    '#00CCCC',
    '#00CCFF',
    '#3300CC',
    '#3300FF',
    '#3333CC',
    '#3333FF',
    '#3366CC',
    '#3366FF',
    '#3399CC',
    '#3399FF',
    '#33CC00',
    '#33CC33',
    '#33CC66',
    '#33CC99',
    '#33CCCC',
    '#33CCFF',
    '#6600CC',
    '#6600FF',
    '#6633CC',
    '#6633FF',
    '#66CC00',
    '#66CC33',
    '#9900CC',
    '#9900FF',
    '#9933CC',
    '#9933FF',
    '#99CC00',
    '#99CC33',
    '#CC0000',
    '#CC0033',
    '#CC0066',
    '#CC0099',
    '#CC00CC',`

Comment: can you also add example of your txt file?

Comment: If you're working on an http file server you shouldn't be using `readFileSync`, that will tank your performance because your server won't be able to handle new requests while it's waiting to read the file.

Comment: @david There won't be alot of traffic, so no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are doing `console.log`?
I did `console.log` and didn't get any "+", but I got those when I use `console.dir`.
Anyway, these "+", are not part of the string and you can't remove them by using split.

And just use the string as if they were not there.

To get each line simply use:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
let file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/text.txt", { encoding: "utf8" });

const lines = file.split("\n");
```